# Keeping Application.ScreenUpdating = False After Running Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a hotkey that will toggle Application.ScreenUpdating. I just learned that the newer Excel versions automatically reset Application.ScreenUpdating to true after running a macro which is good 99.99% of the time except I don't want that to happen I want it to be persistent. Is there anyway for me to keep Application.ScreenUpdating = False?

```
Sub suspend_screen_update()

    MsgBox "1st " & Application.ScreenUpdating

    If Application.ScreenUpdating = True Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
    MsgBox "2nd " & Application.ScreenUpdating

End Sub

Private Sub hk_toggle_screen_update()
    Application.OnKey "{F1}", suspend_screen_update
End Sub
```

Why? My boss sometimes request that I only use Excel, nothing else, to manipulate a lot of data. Excel can be super slow if not crash when the data gets really big. I'm trying to save us time by creating this hotkey.

Comment: How are you going to interact with Excel if screen updating is off and a macro is not running?

Comment: You could get ahold of the application's hWnd, and invoke some Win32 to prevent repainting regardless of `Application.ScreenUpdating`. I've used it to quickly flash some shapes in a game, it allows for tighter delays. ...but *leave repaint off after the macro completes* ...that's asking "how do I make Excel look like it's bugged up and unresponsive and just about to crash on me?" - you'll have to clarify the *why* of this.

Comment: Hide the entire application (`Application.Visible = False`). IIR Excel will not attempt to repaint if the window state is hidden.

Comment: I wouldn't set it to the `F1` key. Users may want to press that one for help. `F5` may be a better candidate.

Comment: I am not sure about your statement that Excel resets the screen updating, but even if it is true it does not have anything to do with the performance if you turn it off at the beginning of your main macro

Comment: Application.Visible = False is indeed persistent but then the hotkey doesn't work because I can't select the application haha. That was a good suggestion though.

I ultimately decided to not make a toggle key and just have my macro/hotkey suspend screenupdating for five seconds only. This has made my calculations a lot faster. 
Thank you!